# Is impulse functionally equivalent to work and therefore expressible in Joules?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, energy, work

I am trying to understand things at at a fundamental and conceptual level.
Givens...

1. 1 kg mass
2. Mass is at rest (relatively, of course)
3. Mass is on an idealized frictionless surface
4. 1 N of force is applied by me (or an authorized agent of mine acting as a fiduciary should I be unable to perform my duties herein described) ;)
5. The force is applied through 1 M

I believe that since 1N = is the force required to accelerate 1kg 1M/s^2, after 1 second the mass will have moved 1M.
At that point I (or my fiduciary)  would stop exerting the force and I will have done 1 joule of work.  But I will also...by necessity.. have imparted 1 Ns of impulse.

So I have 3 questions

1. Is it true that after 1 sec the mass will have moved 1M?
2. If so is it not also true that, at least in this case,  1Ns  = 1J  (indirectly but inextricably).
3. Wouldn’t this also be true for every conceivable situation in which a such a force was exerted on any such mass? This would be because there is always one and only 1 impulse that could possibly be associated with that work, and hence they are functionally equivalent, meaning that, assuming the mass in question was at rest and moved at least 1 meter, impulse could be expressed in terms of joules, and work could be expressed in Ns? I know this may not be practical to do or to calculate, but I am interested in if it is true conceptually.

Thanks.. and please forgive my poor attempt at humor ... my lawyer says that physics is becoming rather litigious!

Comment: The statement is not correct: "I believe that since 1N = is the force required to accelerate 1kg 1M/s^2, after 1 second the mass will have moved 1M". $S=v_0 t + a t^2/1$, therefore, it is 0.5 M if $v_0=0$..

Comment: Impulse is $F\Delta t$. It is not unit of energy.

Answer (score 0):

1. If I understood correctly, in your question you apply a constant force of $F=1~N$ to a body of $m=1~kg$ mass during $t=1~s$. If so, after that time your body will be moving at a speed of $v=Ft/m=1~m/s$. Now if you are interested in the total distance covered by the body, you first have to look at its equation of motion. Note that the speed $v$ depends on $t$, meaning that during that $1~s$ period the body will be accelerating. So you have to integrate and you get $x=\int_0^t v(t')dt'=Ft^2/2$.
2. You have done work on the body and this work has increased the energy of it. The energy of the body will be $E=mv^2/2=F^2t^2/2m$. By definition $1~J=1~N\times 1~m$, not $1~N\times1~s$. As you can see from the equation, the relation between $F\times t$ (that's what you mean by "Ns" I guess) and the energy (or work) depends on the mass of the body too. If you take a lighter body and apply equal force its energy will be higher.
3. To your last question, I suppose you mean the following. If you consider a model where all bodies have masses of $1~kg$, then yes, you can measure energy in newtons times second (squared). This is a bit like with electromagnetic waves: because their propagation speed $c$ is constant, you can measure frequency in Hz, in nanometers (would normally be wavelength) or inverse centimeters (would be wavenumbers). It is possible to unambiguously recalculate one to another. But if your parameters change (like $c$), this relation between different units is no longer valid.